# typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i; what does this definition mean?

Tags: c++

I am back to C++ after about 5 years. I quickly review it. But there is a definition I do not know.

`std::vector` is a class template.

```
typedef Vec<int, 2> Vec2i;
typedef Vec<int, 3> Vec3i;
typedef Vec<int, 4> Vec4i;
typedef Vec<int, 6> Vec6i;
typedef Vec<int, 8> Vec8i;
```

I do not know what are the numbers for? Does it mean the bytes?

It is from `core.hpp`.

```
/*!
  A short numerical vector.

  This template class represents short numerical vectors (of 1, 2, 3, 4 ... elements)
  on which you can perform basic arithmetical operations, access individual elements using [] operator etc.
  The vectors are allocated on stack, as opposite to std::valarray, std::vector, cv::Mat etc.,
  which elements are dynamically allocated in the heap.

  The template takes 2 parameters:
  -# _Tp element type
  -# cn the number of elements

  In addition to the universal notation like Vec<float, 3>, you can use shorter aliases
  for the most popular specialized variants of Vec, e.g. Vec3f ~ Vec<float, 3>.
*/
template<typename _Tp, int cn> class Vec : public Matx<_Tp, cn, 1>
```

Comment: Without knowing what `Vec` is, it is not possible to answer this definitively. It is *likely* `Vec` is a template that takes a type and size magnitude to declare a fixed array. And fwiw, if that is the case it is obsolete, as we now have [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) with C++11. And the opening, "`std::vector` is a class template" is meaningless to the rest of this question.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It wouldn't be obsolete if it had additional member functions or operators defined.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I guess we'll never know.

Comment: "What is the difference with the follows?" Parse error, bailing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, `Vec` is a class template representing N-dimensional mathematical vectors which looks something like:

```
template <typename T, int N> class Vec { /* ... */ };
```

The numbers specify the number of elements in the vector, i.e. a 2D vector with integer components, a 3D vector with integer components, etc.

But without the code it's impossible to say.